# ExtJs Fieldset Collapsed issue

Tags: extjs

I have a `fieldset` with the option `checkboxToggle:true`. When the user checks/unchecks the checkbox, I don't want the `fieldset` to expand/collapse.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your problem is. You should add your existing code to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement the `beforecollapse` event on the `fieldset` like in the code below. But this way you won't be able to collapse the `fieldset`.

Setting `collapsible: false` doesn't seem to work.

```
xtype:'fieldset',
checkboxToggle:true,
title: 'User Information',
autoHeight:true,
defaults: {width: 210},
defaultType: 'textfield',
items :[{
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        name: 'first',
        allowBlank:false
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
        name: 'last'
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Company',
        name: 'company'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Email',
        name: 'email',
        vtype:'email'
    }
],
listeners: {
    beforecollapse : function(p) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay.. Is there any event to hide some controls in fieldset based on checkbox check/uncheck events   ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

or override Fieldset

```
Ext.override( Ext.form.FieldSet, {

    onCheckChange: function(cmp, checked) {
        if(this.collapsible) this.setExpanded(checked);
    }

});
```